# Supabase where can I see my replication slot?

Tags: supabase

I want to connect my supabase postgres with airbyte and I have to enter my replication slot name.

I go to my dashboard and then to replication. I saw this:
[image]

So I entered supabase_realtime but I got this error:

```
Could not connect with provided configuration. Error: Expected exactly one replication slot but found 0. Please read the docs and add a replication slot to your database.
```

But why I got this error ? I entered my replication slot.

Comment: Please reach out to the supabase support team: https://supabase.com/dashboard/support/new